# Cordova won't fetch anything base64, no matter what's in the CSP

Tags: javascript, cordova, base64, cordova-plugins, content-security-policy

I'm using Cordova's camera plugin to allow my app to take photos, and so far just cannot get it to do anything with the returned data.

I've given up on trying to load it from the filesystem URL, and am now trying with base64.

My CSP is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src *; 
    style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; 
    script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
    media-src *; 
    img-src * data:; 
    connect-src * ws: wss:;
" />
```

...however I've tried every other CSP I can find on the internet. No matter what's in there, my console always logs:

> "Refused to connect to 'data:image/jpg;base64... because it violates
>   the document's Content Security Policy.", source:
>   http://localhost:8080/js/main.js"

Does anyone know why this is the case, or how I'd go about fixing it?

The code to turn the image data into a file is:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(response => {
    this.urltoFile('data:image/jpg;base64,'+response, 'test.jpg')
        .then(file => {
            console.log(file);
        })
    }, () => {}, {
    destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
})
```

...and the `urlToFile` function is:

```
urltoFile(url, filename){
    let mimeType = (url.match(/^data:([^;]+);/)||'')[1];

    return (fetch(url)
        .then(res => {
            return res.arrayBuffer();
        })
        .then(buf => {
            return new File([buf], filename, { 
                type: mimeType 
            });
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code where you're trying to _load_ the photo?

Comment: Good point! Updated.

Comment: Could you try to add `data:` to your connect-src? Like `connect-src * data: ws: wss:;`

Comment: Oh my god @Phonolog thank you so much. Perhaps set this as an answer and I'll give it a tick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code you are using the Fetch API to download pictures as base64.

Looking at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src), the Fetch API is restricted by the `connect-src` directive (emphasis is mine):

> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) `connect-src` directive restricts
>   the URLs which can be loaded using script interfaces. The APIs that
>   are restricted are:
>
> - `<a> ping`,
> - **`Fetch`**,
> - `XMLHttpRequest`,
> - `WebSocket`, and
> - `EventSource`.

So we'll have to alter your `connect-src` to accept [data Urls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) by adding `data:` to the directive like so:

```
connect-src * data: ws: wss:;
```

Comment: One quick last one, just cause I'm useless at CSP stuff - if I change it back to fetch from the device's URL (instead of loading base64), would adding this to the CSP enable it to fetch correctly there also?